# CSS: Vertical align p in span in button...or not?

Tags: html, css, button, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

So I have this code:

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" id="button" name="send-message">
    <span class="content">Lorem ipsum</span>
    <span class="container"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p</span>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.container p {
    background: yellow;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLN4W/)

I tried all day to get the `<p>` vertically centered inside the `span`, without success. The problem is that this button has to be responsive: If the text does not fit into one line, it has to flow into the second one. This works as you can see, but it does not look that nice because the text is on top of the button instead of being nicely centered.

The class `container` is meant to be some kind of overlay, thats why I left `.content` in there to show what I mean.

Actually the problem could be the `position: absolute`, but I have no idea to perform that task without it as I need to cover IE8+, (mobile) Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

If there is a simpler solution for this problem I would love to hear about it as I am not a fan of the markup used for this effect.

Please help me!

Comment: did you mean like this ? [see](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/nLN4W/1/)

Comment: @anonymousxxx Basically yes, but as soon there are two lines, the second line has no "padding" - there is no space between the edge of the button and the `p`. Is seems that only the first line is centered and the second line flows below.

Comment: That markup is invalid:  spans can't contain paragraphs.  I'm shocked your selectors worked at all.

Comment: @Sven : try this http://jsfiddle.net/nLN4W/5/ is this you needed...?

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks for the heads up, you're right! Shouldn't be a big deal to swap that out for another span - although that does not make it prettier.

Comment: @Pandian That seems to be the best solution so far!

Comment: @Sven : Ok then I have added that to the answer...

Comment: sorry I was really confused as to what do you want, I try again I hope this is what you mean [see](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/nLN4W/6/)

Comment: @anonymousxxx No problem at all - I am really glad when people try to help me! Unfortunately, now the text even overflows the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `Height : 100%` to `line-height:60px;` on `CSS .container {}` will get work...

Try this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nLN4W/5/